# How to combine data frames in pandas that are one below the other?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

```
list_1  =[1, 2, 3, 4 ]

def fun(list_1):
    for each value in list1:
        # perform some operation and create a new data frame(pandas) for each value in the list
        # so in total I should get 4 data frames.

        yield new_data_frame
```

When I call fun(list_1) I get 4 data frames one below the other:

```
data_frame_1

data_frame_2

data_frame_3

data_frame_4
```

My question is, what if I need to combine the pandas data frames vertically?

```
data_frame_1
+
data_frame_2
+
data_frame_3
+
data_frame_4
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Store them in a list and then `pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)`

or

`pd.concat([data_frame_1, data_frame_2, data_frame_3, data_frame_4],ignore_index=True)`

os simpler just pass the fun as arg to [`pd.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat):

```
In [8]:

list_1 = [1,2,3,4]
def fun(list_1):
    for each_value in list_1:
        # perform some operation and create a new data frame(pandas) named "new_data_frame" for each value in the list

        yield pd.DataFrame({'a':[each_value]})
pd.concat(fun(list_1), ignore_index=True)
Out[8]:
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
```

Comment: Thats magical!! It worked.  can you explain what ignore_index =True does here?

Comment: `ignore_index` essentially reindexes the concatenated dataframes, otherwise you'll get duplicate index values

Answer (score 1):

Store the data frame in a list like so:

```
dflist = [df1,df2,df3]
```

and to add them one below one, use this command:

```
pd.concat(dflist, ignore_index=True)
```